# Increase Kinect's limit of people recognition

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I need to create system, which is recognizing human bodies in some place. I suppose, Kinect is the most available in this area. But it has one limitation - it can recognise only 6 people. Is it possible to increase this value? I do not need skeleton tracking, but I need to recognize standing and sitting people.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately kinect can only recognize up to 6 people at onces..

http://www.ign.com/videos/2013/11/20/xbox-one-how-many-people-can-kinect-handle
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973074.aspx